# Error during executing an endpoint of my API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, endpoint

I am fairly new to ASP.NET Web APIs in general and I cannot quite understand and solve the following error I get when trying to execute an endpoint I have created in my project:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'NIA.Application.IIPDetailsService' while attempting to activate 'NIA.API.Controllers.IPDetailsController'.

In my `Startup.cs`, I have defined the dependency

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IIPDetailsService, IPDetailsService>();
}
```

In my `IPDetails.Controller.cs`, I have this constructor

```
public IPDetailsController(IIPDetailsService ipDetailsService, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _ipDetailsService = ipDetailsService;
    _cache = memoryCache;
}
```

My `IIPDetailsService.cs` interface looks like this

```
public interface IIPDetailsService
{
    Task<IPDetailsResponseDto> GetIPDetails(string ipAddress);
}
```

and my `IPDetailsService.cs` implementation is this:

```
public class IPDetailsService : IIPDetailsService
{
    private readonly IIPDetailsRepository _ipDetailsRepository;

    public IPDetailsService(IIPDetailsRepository ipDetailsRepository)
    {
        _ipDetailsRepository = ipDetailsRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IPDetailsResponseDto> GetIPDetails(string ipAddress)
    {
        // Call the repository to get IP details
        IPDetails ipDetails = await _ipDetailsRepository.GetIPDetails(ipAddress);

        // Convert IPDetails to IPDetailsResponseDto
        IPDetailsResponseDto responseDto = new IPDetailsResponseDto
        {
            // Map properties from IPDetails to IPDetailsResponseDto
            // ...
        };

        return responseDto;
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me understand the following error I get whenever I debug the solution, try out and execute the endpoint:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'NIA.Application.IIPDetailsService' while attempting to activate 'NIA.API.Controllers.IPDetailsController'.

Any help is appreciated. If any more info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The likely case of this error is that there is a second type in your application that is called `IIPDetailsService`. Your controller is referencing this second type `NIA.API.Controllers.IPDetailsController`, while the type you registered, and which the `IPDetailsService` class implements, is located in a different namespace/assembly.

This error is quite common, because modern IDEs, like Visual Studio, allow generating types with almost a single keystroke. Although very convenient, it makes it easy to accidentally generate such type and confuse the DI Container.

Another unfortunate flaw in Microsoft's container is that it doesn't detect the existence of identically-named registration and inform you that this might be the cause of your trouble. Containers that do have this feature can prevent you hours of chasing your own tail.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. 
I am currently trying to find all instances of the wording IIPDetailsService and I only use it in my IIPDetailsService.cs where I set it as an Interface.

In IPDetailsService,cs where I use the interface as like 
public class IPDetailsService : IIPDetailsService. 

in the IPDetailsController.cs as I mentioned above  and in my startup.cs.